# How to create an alias for the current session?

Tags: bash, unix, alias

If you use an alias in a terminal, e.g. alias a=b it will stay in the current terminal, but if you open another terminal you have to set up the alias again. In order to make the alias permanent you can add the alias to the .bash_profile and this will apply it to all the terminals permanently.
My question is how to set up an alias for all the terminals but only for the current session, i.e. if I log out the alias is gone.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The general concept is to create a file like `.session_aliases` which contain your session aliases, then put a line like (notice the spaces around the `[`, `]`, and the `.` before `.session_aliases`—these are required):

```
[ -f .session_aliases ] && . .session_aliases
```

in your `.bashrc` (or `.profile` or `.bash_profile` or whatever). Then you just need to set up a script, run at session logout, which removes `.session_aliases`.

However, a quick search for "xlogout" suggests that there doesn't seem to be a universal script that gets called when you log out of your session. So the answer is going to be display-manager-specific.

You didn't mention which display manager you use, so I'm going to assume lightdm (given that that's the standard display manager for Ubuntu and Ubuntu is the most common distribution). You can follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/68407/3334) to set up a logout script when you end your lightdm session.

If you use a different display manager, the procedure will be different. Google is your friend. :-)